# Can we use Plots.jl plots within Escher.jl

Tags: plot, julia, plots.jl

I'm trying to determine if it's possible to use the Plots package within Escher GUIs. has anyone successfully done this?

Comment: I talked with @tbreloff about this. We both weren't able to get Escher.jl working to actually try it.

Comment: Escher can be buggy sometimes. It works well for me on 0.4, but I've not tried is on 0.5 yet.

Comment: That must be it. We're both on v0.5/v0.6... note that many of the latest Plots.jl features require v0.5

Comment: Thanks. It will probably take some time then before this is possible.